# Как переделать это код на vue js?

Tags: jquery, vue.js

Есть код на `jquery` который при клике на элемент меняет значение `display` другого элемента:

```
$('.header__user-image').click( function(){
    $('.header__list').toggleClass('header__list_active');
});
```

Как переделать этот код на `Vue.js`, и куда его вставлять? ( в `main.js` или в `Component.vue` ? )

Comment: Повесьте `@click` на элемент(я так понимаю это картинка), который будет вызывать функцию, где будет ваш код  ( открытие/закрытие листа)

Answer (score 2):

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    active: true,
  },
  methods: {
    example(){
      this.active = !this.active;
      console.log(this.active);
    },
  },
})
```

```css
.blue{
  color:blue;
}
.red{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <template>
    <div
      @click="example"
    >
      <span
        :class="{blue:active, red:!active}"
      >
        Привет
      </span>
    <div>
  </template>
</div>
```

[Документация.](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, сейчас допилим, не получается в стеке запустить)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, подправил. Минус можно убрать.

Comment: Поправил вам yellow на blue, а то уж больно "хорошо" желтый на белом смотрится.

Comment: @PavelMayorov добро)

Answer (score 0):

Где то в разметке:
Элемент, по которому надо кликнуть:

```
<img @click="myFuncton" />
```

Элемент, которому надо поменять класс:

```
<div ref='myElement'></div>
```

Где то в `vue`:

```
...
methods: {
  myFunction(){
    this.$refs.myElement.toggleClass('header__list_active');
  }
}
...
```