# Где объявлять значения переменных чтобы они были доступны всем компонентам?

Tags: vue.js

Хочу задать значения некоторым переменным:

```
data () {
        return {
            ulMenuHeader: false,
            userSalt: 'unknown',
            userId: '0'
        }
    },
mounted() {
        if ( localStorage.userSalt ) { this.userSalt = localStorage.userSalt  }
        if ( localStorage.userId ) { this.userId = localStorage.userId  }
    }
```

Если я это сделаю, например в **MyComp1.vue** - и там же это вывожу - значение выводит. А уже в **MyComp2.vue** - ругается что такой переменной нет.

Обе компоненты импортированы в **main.js**, пробовал объявить эти переменные в **main.js** - в итоге в **MyComp1.vue** и  в **MyComp2.vue** - переменные не известны.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1001662/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bd%d0%b0-vue-js/1001690#1001690 Ни один ответ вас не устроил?

Comment: @doox911 я же отметил решение, оно было в другом вопросе

Comment: Используйте [vuex](https://habr.com/ru/post/421551/) для хранения глобальных переменных, чтобы использовать их в любом компоненте

Comment: @radar4ick дайте ответ.